# Can you use quadro drivers on a Geforce card (500 or 600 series)?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

I remember reading about these 4-5 years ago, but not sure if they are still doing it. Is this possible nowadays? Basically running a GTX like a Quadro? I don't know much about hardware, but some people were saying since the GTX cards come out more often, they have alot of stuff hardware wise that Quadros don't. And so they can be used just like a Quadro with proper drivers.

Where should I be looking at to do this sort of thing? Also is there any risk of damaging the card?

Answer (score 3):

*Just like* is a little over simplified. They are comparable, but stability and performance is not the same.

Some have even gone as far as flashing GTX cards to think they are running QUADRO firmware. There are still issues with performance and  stability as the hardware is not identical.

Largely, it depends on what you want to use this for. Just a side project, then its probably OK. If you actually want to get work done for work or a business, then I would spend the money on a decent Quadro card and save time and money in the long run.

Comment: Thanks yeah I need to use it for work but quadros are way too expensive for me. And people were claiming that latest gtx cards like 690 etc are way more powerful than the latest quadros.

Comment: For CAD and similar applications the hardware is the essentially the same. The biggest difference is instruction sets and drivers. A Quadro won't run Crysis as well as a consumner card, but a consumer card also won't run MAYA nearly as well as Quadro. If you look at something like the video below, the Quadro completes in 10 minutes vs 17.5 for the 670. Looks like the Quadro is the cheaper card now too
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl4yNCgD3iA